# How to make image fit width in SubsamplingScaleImageView (davemorrissey lib)

Tags: android

While current code :-

`setMinimumScaleType(SubsamplingScaleImageView.SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP)`

works well for matching the shortest of the image's dimensions, and

`setMinimumScaleType(SubsamplingScaleImageView.SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_INSIDE)`

works for matching the widest dimension, there doesn't seem to be any way to specifically match width or height?

Answer (score 1):

My method for matching width was as follows

```
public void instantiateItem() {
    ...
    _ssiImageView.setMinimumScaleType(SubsamplingScaleImageView.SCALE_TYPE_CUSTOM);
    _ssiImageView.setMinScale(getFitWidthScale());
    ...
}

private float getFitWidthScale(){
    float windowWidth = App.getWindowWidth(); //Acquires window's pixel width
    return = windowWidth/getImageWidth();
}

private float getImageWidth(){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    return options.outWidth;
}
```

This only works correctly, if the SubsamplingScaleImageView fills the entire screen width. Basically the window width and view width needs to be the same. But, if you can acquire the SubsamplingScaleImageView's pixel width, you could just use that instead of the windowWidth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setImage(ImageSource imageSource, ImageViewState state)` method like this:

```
ssiImageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(Uri.fromFile(new File(imgFilePath))), new ImageViewState(getFitWidthScale(), new PointF(0, 0), SubsamplingScaleImageView.ORIENTATION_USE_EXIF));

private float getFitWidthScale(){
    float windowWidth = App.getWindowWidth(); //Acquires window's pixel width
    return = windowWidth/getImageWidth();
}

private float getImageWidth(){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
    return options.outWidth;
}
```